# append image with form data using axios patch giving error

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to append  image with form data the problem is that if image is not passed  i get error `submitted data is not file`
because image is passed as undefined

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", image);//if image is empty dont append image with form data

Object.entries(Data).forEach(([key, value]) => formData.append(key, value)); 

axios.patch("url-for-api/", formData, config)
```

if the image is undefinnd axios patch is giving error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const formData = new FormData();
      
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(values)) {
    if (value) {
      formData.append(key, value);
    }
}
axios.patch("url-for-api/", formData, config)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = new FormData(); if (image != undefined) {
      formData.append("prescription", image);
    }
Object.entries(Data).forEach(([key, value]) => formData.append(key, value)); 

axios.patch("url-for-api/", formData, config)
```

Comment: Is this a solution to your problem?